# mover personaje con sprites en pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game

El sprite se mueve, en el juego, el problema es que cada vez que toco una tecla, no se actyualiza, les muestro el codigo de granjero.py
Quiero decir, el juego funciona correctamente, ahora, el problema radica que cuando tocó "W", el sprite no se actualiza y no se como arreglarlo, estuve buscando ayuda y nada me ayuda ;c

Me pide que agrege mas detalles, así que lo intentaré. bueno, en principio tenia un problema que no me cargaba el juego pero pude solucionarlo, ahora el problema es que el sprite no se mueve o sea, se mueve pero no cambia la animacion. tengo todo perfectamente cargado y todo eso, solo el problema es que no se me carga las animaciones ;c. he buscado en internet como arreglarlo y ninguno me pudo solucionar.

```
 import pygame
import tamaño
class Granjero:
    def __init__(self):
        self.imagen = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/granjero.png")
        self.sprites = []
        self.recortar_sprites()
        self.sprite_actual = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(5, 120, 30, 43)
        self.direccion = "abajo"
        self.sprites_arriba = []
        self.sprites_abajo = []
        self.sprites_izquierda = []
        self.sprites_derecha = []
        
    def recortar_sprites(self):
        #Cargar imagen con los sprites
        sprites_image = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/granjero.png")

        #Obtener sub-superficie del primer sprite (caminando hacia arriba)
        sprite_arriba1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0,129 ,30, 43))
        sprite_arriba2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(21, 29, 30, 43))
        sprite_arriba3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86.21, 129, 30, 43))
        sprite_arriba4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 129, 30, 43))
        #sprite_arriba5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 129, 30, 43))
        #sprite_arriba6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 129, 30, 43))
        #Obtener sub-superficie del segundo sprite (caminando hacia arriba)
        sprite_derecha1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 86, 30, 43))
        sprite_derecha2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 86, 30, 43))
        sprite_derecha3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86, 86, 30, 43))
        sprite_derecha4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 86, 30, 43))
        #sprite_derecha5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 86, 30, 43))
        #sprite_derecha6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 86, 30, 43))
        
        sprite_izquierda1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 44, 30, 43))
        sprite_izquierda2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 44, 30, 43))
        sprite_izquierda3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86, 44, 30, 43))
        sprite_izquierda4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 44, 30, 43))
        #sprite_izquierda5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 44, 30, 43))
        #sprite_izquierda6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 44, 30, 43))

        sprite_abajo1 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 30, 43))
        sprite_abajo2 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(41, 0, 30, 43)) 
        sprite_abajo3 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(86, 0, 30, 43))
        sprite_abajo4 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(133, 0, 30, 43))
        #sprite_abajo5 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(174, 0, 30, 43))
        #sprite_abajo6 = sprites_image.subsurface(pygame.Rect(220, 0, 30, 43))

        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_arriba6)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_derecha6)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_izquierda6)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo1)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo2)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo3)
        self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo4)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo5)
        #self.sprites.append(sprite_abajo6)
        self.sprites_arriba = [sprite_arriba1, sprite_arriba2, sprite_arriba3, sprite_arriba4]
        self.sprites_abajo = [sprite_abajo1, sprite_abajo2, sprite_abajo3, sprite_abajo4]
        self.sprites_izquierda = [sprite_izquierda1, sprite_izquierda2, sprite_izquierda3, sprite_izquierda4]
        self.sprites_derecha = [sprite_derecha1, sprite_derecha2,sprite_derecha3,sprite_derecha4]

    def dibujar(self):
        tamaño.ventana.blit(self.sprites[self.sprite_actual], self.rect)

    def update(self):
        teclas = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if teclas[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.direccion == "arriba":
                self.rect.y -= 2
                self.sprite_actual += 1
            if self.sprite_actual >= len(self.sprites_arriba):
                self.sprite_actual = 0
            self.imagen = self.sprites_arriba[self.sprite_actual]
        elif self.direccion == "abajo":
            self.rect.y += 2
            self.sprite_actual += 1
            if self.sprite_actual >= len(self.sprites_abajo):
                self.sprite_actual = 0
            self.imagen = self.sprites_abajo[self.sprite_actual]
        elif self.direccion == "izquierda":
            self.rect.x -= 2
            self.sprite_actual += 1
            if self.sprite_actual >= len(self.sprites_izquierda):
                self.sprite_actual = 0
                self.imagen = self.sprites_izquierda[self.sprite_actual]
        elif self.direccion == "derecha":
            self.rect.x += 2
            self.sprite_actual += 1
            if self.sprite_actual >= len(self.sprites_derecha):
                self.sprite_actual = 0
                self.imagen = self.sprites_derecha[self.sprite_actual]
```

y principal.py es así;

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import tamaño
from granjero import Granjero
from Enemigo import Enemigo1


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Tu hermana 1")




   
granjero = Granjero()
enemigo = Enemigo1()
    
fondojuego = pygame.image.load("juegos/imagenes/fondonivel.jpg")
tamaño.ventana.blit(fondojuego,(0,0))
tamaño.ventana.blit(granjero.sprites[granjero.sprite_actual], granjero.rect)
pygame.mixer.music.load("juegos/musica/bebe.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)

pygame.mixer.music.play()
reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
fuente = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)


while True:
        
    enemigo.movimiento_aleatorio()
    reloj.tick(30) # 30 fps
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.unicode == "w":
                    granjero.rect.y -= 5
                    granjero.direccion = "arriba"
                    
                elif event.unicode == "s":
                    granjero.rect.y += 5
                    granjero.direccion = "abajo"
                    
                elif event.unicode == "a":
                    granjero.rect.x -= 5
                    granjero.direccion ="izquierda"
                   
                elif event.unicode == "d":
                    granjero.rect.x += 5
                    granjero.sprites_derecha
        enemigo.movimiento_aleatorio()
        
        pygame.display.update()
        reloj.tick(60)
        
        
        if granjero.rect.colliderect(enemigo.rect):
            granjero.vida -= 1
            enemigo.rect.x = random.randint(10, 1200)
            enemigo.rect.y = random.randint(10, 600)

       
       
        

        tamaño.ventana.blit(fondojuego, (0, 0))
        tamaño.ventana.blit(granjero.sprites[granjero.sprite_actual], granjero.rect)
        tamaño.ventana.blit(enemigo.sprites[enemigo.sprite_actual], enemigo.rect)

        #tamaño.ventana.blit(puntos_texto, (10, 10))
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        

       


        ###puntos_texto = fuente.render("Puntos: " + str(puntos), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        
        #tamaño.ventana.blit(puntos_texto, (10, 10))
       
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()

        reloj.tick(130)
```

Comment: El metodo update del granjero, el cual se encarga de actualizar que sprite se muestra, nunca es llamado. De ahí que no cambie.

Comment: Lo mismo pasa con draw. Por que creaste esos metodos si no les vas a dar uso?